# React application built with Apollo-GraphQL, MongoDB-Mongoose, and Node-Express returning a 404 error in production build

Tags: reactjs, react-router, apollo-client, react-apollo, apollo-server

I am learning about React. I have a React application that is using a google api to allow logged in users to search and save books to a Mongo database. Everything works correctly in development but when I run my build for production, I get a 404 error that the request path cannot be found.

My server-side server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express');
const path = require('path');
const db = require('./config/connection');
const { typeDefs, resolvers } = require('./schemas');
const { authMiddleware } = require('./utils/auth');


const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: authMiddleware
});
server.applyMiddleware({ app });

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

// if we're in production, serve client/build as static assets
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build')));
}

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build/index.html'));
});


db.once('open', () => {
  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`API server running on port ${PORT}!`);
    console.log(`Use GraphQL at http://localhost:${PORT}${server.graphqlPath}`);
  });
});
```

My client-side App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import SearchBooks from './pages/SearchBooks';
import SavedBooks from './pages/SavedBooks';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import {
  ApolloClient,
  InMemoryCache,
  ApolloProvider,
  HttpLink,
  ApolloLink,
  from
} from "@apollo/client";
import { onError } from '@apollo/client/link/error';

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: '/graphql'
});

const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors)
    graphQLErrors.forEach(({ message, locations, path }) =>
      console.log(
        `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`,
      ),
    );

  if (networkError) console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
});

const tokenLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
  operation.setContext({
      headers: {
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : 'No token found in App.js'
      }
  });
  return forward(operation);
 });

const client = new ApolloClient({
  // The `from` function combines an array of individual links
  // into a link chain
  link: from([errorLink, tokenLink, httpLink]),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

function App() {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Router>
        <>
          <Navbar />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={SearchBooks} />
            <Route exact path='/saved' component={SavedBooks} />
            <Route render={() => <h1 className='display-2'>Wrong page!</h1>} />
          </Switch>
        </>
      </Router>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my first time asking a question, so if other information is needed/helpful, please let me know and I will edit the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had help, and someone pointed out I did not include a .env folder when I thought I already had! Sometimes it is the simple things.